# Почему при дробных значениях алгоритм не работает?

Tags: delphi, алгоритм, pascal, delphi-7

Задача следующая:

> Ввести целое число a и вывести сумму квадратов всех чисел от 1 до a с шагом 0.1. (1^2+1.1^2+1.2^2+...+a^2)

Алгоритм решения такой:

```
result := 0
while (a >= 1) do begin
    result := result + a * a;
    a := a - 0.1;
end;
```

В конце работы программы результат должен быть:

```
При a = 1.1 result = 2.21
При a = 3 result = 91.7
```

Переменная `a`, в любом случае, при завершении программы должна быть равна `0.9`.

Проблема в следующем. При `a = 1.1` все верно, но начиная с `1.2` и далее программа выдает в результате на 1 меньше, чем нужно: `a = 3; result = 90.7`, при этом, в конце выполнения программы, `a = 0.9(9)`.

Если модифицировать алгоритм: переменную `a` после ввода умножать на 10, а затем в цикле в квадрат возводить не ее, а выражение `a / 10`, то все начинает работать правильно (второй строкой в цикле здесь будет: `a := a - 1`).

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: проблема в представлении дробных чисел в двоичном виде. Вкратце - 0.2 невозможно представить точно.

Comment: @kami, значит, модифицированный алгоритм - единственное решение проблемы?

Comment: В Вашем случае - возможно. Но стоит попробовать так: для сравнения вещественных чисел следует использовать Math.SameValue и Math.CompareValue (думаю, они есть в D7). Емнип, на СО есть объяснение этому эффекту, но с ходу не нашел...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что числа представлены в двоичном виде. Десятичное значение 0,1 не может быть представлено в двоичном виде конечной дробью, оно равно 0,0001100110011...<sub>2</sub> или 0,0(0011)<sub>2</sub> в стандартной записи рациональных дробей.

У чисел с плавающей точкой с двойной точностью хранится 53 двоичных знака после запятой, бесконечная часть дроби отбрасывается. В результате вместо точного значения 0,1 мы имеем число 0,1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. Если вы выведете его на печать с не очень большой точностью, вы получите 0,1, но это только результат округления. При округлении до 17-го знака получается 0,100000000000000001, и последний знак участвует в вычислениях. Поэтому, два раза вычитая из 1,2 значение 0,1, вы получаете число меньшее 1.

Простого решения подобных проблем на все случаи жизни не существует. Простейшим в вашем случае будет эмуляция чисел с фиксированной запятой, например так, как вы и сделали.

Можно упростить вычисления, посчитав суммы квадратов целых чисел, и разделив результат на 100:

a<sup>2</sup> + (a + 0.1)<sup>2</sup> + (a + 0.2)<sup>2</sup> + ... =

(10a)<sup>2</sup>/100 + (10a + 1)<sup>2</sup>/100 + (10a + 2)<sup>2</sup>/100 + ...

Можно использовать библиотеки, которые обеспечивают работу с рациональными числами, с числами в десятичной системе счисления (как тип `decimal` в C#), или с числами большой точности.